# Regular expression to match a unknown length string ending in partially known terminator

Tags: regex

I am currently trying to write a regular expression that will extract only the value assigned to the `state:` tag irrespective of the order of the other arguments excluding the title.

**For example:**

```
addcard "My card title" assigned: @username @username2 state: ready to
deploy due: Next Wednesday project: tooling #tag1 #tag2 #tag3

addcard "My card title" state:ready to deploy assigned: @username 
@username2 due: Next Wednesday project: tooling #tag1 #tag2 #tag3

addcard "My card title" #tag1 #tag2 #tag3 state: ready to deploy 
assigned: @username @username2 due: Next Wednesday project: tooling
```

Should all return: `ready to deploy` or `state:ready to deploy` or `state: ready to deploy`

I tried my luck at using a negative lookup , but I'm starting to think I may not understand negative lookups well enough.

My current regular expression: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/YoRI2A/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

`state:([\w\s]+)\s`

https://regex101.com/r/b4Xw92/1

Answer (score 0):

@Jack's answer is clever in that the pattern used, also omits the terminator cleverly because it indicates we want to match with a word that ends in a space. The terminator is a word that ends with a colon.

A refinement to @Jack's answer is to omit any leading spaces as well:

```
state:\s*([\w\s]+)\s
```